# How can I create a link to a specific, known page using TypoScript?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I am working on some Typo3 6.2 templates. I want to insert a link into the template using Typoscript.

I have a constant `{$HOME_SHORTCUT}`, which has the title "Startseite" & the path /start. I want the link to look like this:

```
  <a href="/start">Startseite</a>
```

I am using this to insert the link before a set of breadcrumbs. The link path is correct but the value/text of the link is the pageID of `{$HOME_SHORTCUT}`, not the header text, which is what I want:

```
 stdWrap.prepend = TEXT
 stdWrap.prepend {

  value = {$HOME_SHORTCUT} ###HOW DO I USE THE TITLE OF THE PAGE AS THE VALUE?####

  stdWrap.typolink {
    field = header
    parameter = {$HOME_SHORTCUT}
    }
  }
```

This outputs:

```
 <a href="/start">146</a>
```

Which is incorrect. That's the page ID, not the header. How do I get the header of `{$HOME_SHORTCUT}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you leave out the "value" the page title is set automatically:

```
stdWrap.prepend = TEXT
stdWrap.prepend.typolink.parameter = {$HOME_SHORTCUT}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Following along with this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273695/how-can-i-insert-the-current-page-title-automaticly-into-a-typo3-template/1274794#1274794), I constructed this, which gives the desired mark-up:

```
stdWrap.prepend = TEXT
stdWrap.prepend {

  value {
    table = pages
    select {
      where = uid = {$HOME_SHORTCUT}
    }
    renderObj {
      10 = TEXT
      10 {
        field = title
        wrap = |
      }
    }
  }
  stdWrap.typolink {
    field = header
    parameter = {$HOME_SHORTCUT}
  }
}
```

Which seems like a really, really long-winded way of saying "Wrap this page title with a link to this page"- I am definitely interested in hearing of better methods.

Comment: One way to do it is to use a one-element menu, for example a `HMENU` with `special = list` and `special.value = {$HOME_SHORTCUT}`.